# How to bias-correct proportions for a prop.test in R?

Tags: r, proportion, weights, weighted-data, bias-correction

Let's say I ask 200 participants in a study what experience brought the most joy to their lives:
A, B, C, or D.

```
Participants choices:
A: 100/200
B: 50 /200
C: 17 /200
D: 33 /200
```

Using chi2 or prop.tests in R, I found that option A brought most joy to people, with proportions significantly larger for A than for the other three, e.g. for a comparison between A and D:

`prop.test(x = c(100,33), n = c(200,200))`

which produces a significant difference.

However, I have data showing that experience A is generally a more common experience than the other experiences. 190/200 participants did make experience A, but only 45/200 made experience D. Note, that participants can have made multiple experiences in the past, while they could only choose one as the most joyful.

So, what I did was that I weighted the experiences by how frequent they are:

```
x1 = 100 / (190/200)
x2 = 33 / (45/200)
prop.test(x = c(x1,x2), n = c(200,200))
```

Results now show, that option D actually brings more joy, when adjusting for the fact that it is a less common experience.

My question now is, whether this is the right approach to handle this question (e.g., adding the weights but keeping the n constant), or whether there are better ways to analyze this.

Comment: You're using a two-sample test on dependent samples.

Comment: You are right. If I used a chisq.test instead, would the correction make sense, you think?

Comment: You could just alter the inputs to `prop.test` to make it work. With $H_0:\pi=0.5$, the continuity correction generally helps but with the sample sizes you mention it usually doesn't make much practical difference.